# Is it possible to "fake" amount of displayed memory in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I just purchased a second-hand Microsoft Surface laptop from a guy. When we met, he logged in into his windows account and allowed me to play with it. I went to System Information and saw "Installed Physical Memory: 8.00Gb" line - I swear I did. Also the ad mentioned 8Gb. Then I came home, wiped Windows, logged in - and now I have 4Gb of RAM..

This is really frustrating. I wondering if it was me not looking at the right place, or if that was him somehow cheating with the system? Also, while reinstalling Windows, I noticed that harddrive label was "SYSTEM DISK: 2018-11-03" - which makes me to believe he reinstalled Windows just before he sold the laptop.

Am I being paranoid here, or are there ***easy*** ways to "trick" windows 10 and display inaccurate information?..

Comment: Reinstalling before selling is quite a normal thing to do... You didn't accidentally install a 32-bit Windows version, did you?

Comment: 32 bit version of windows is limited to 4 gigs of memory. Well 3,5gig to be more precise. Check if you aren't using a 32-bit version of windows. If so, reinstall a 64-bit version and you should get your memory back.

Comment: @LPChip it's surface laptop - memory is soldered on main board. And windows 10 - i was not aware it's available in 32 bits?? I'm almost positive i did not installed it but I will double check shortly. Thank you for your help

Comment: nah - System Type: x64-based PC - so it's not 32bit problem.

Comment: @avs099 The "System Type" should show both the OS and the CPU. A "x64-based processor" supports a "32-bit operating system". Are you sure you're seeing **64-bit operating system**?

Comment: Go into BIOS and look at the installed memory

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia yes, I went to System -> About and it says 64bit OS as well.

Comment: @Keltari I wish it would be _that_ simple :) https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4023531/surface-how-to-use-surface-uefi  Surface Laptop does not display memory in BIOS..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question: No, you cannot fake the amount of memory in windows. It's impossible to make the system page show 8 gigs of memory if there isn't at least 8 gigs of memory in the system.

It is possible they removed memory after they shown it to you, which could give you this result, but given that you think they reinstalled windows (which I would do too if I sold a device I owned), its possible they and/or you installed a 32-bit version of Windows, which is limited to about 3.5 GB of memory. If this is the case, reinstall windows with a 64-bit version to get your memory back.

Comment: The user could also install the likes of CPU-Z to get system information. It will provide the used banks and the installed memory information to verify with an online source as to capacity. Also, the user should go back to System Information to identify the Windows architecture installed (32/64).

Comment: I'd be surprised if it was truly impossible. Stranger UI modifications have been done.

Comment: @grawity so far I never seen a modification that would allow this. If you have evidence to back up this claim, by all means provide it and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: It's not hard to fake. It wouldn't take long to make a copy of system information in visual studio. Probably longer than it's worth...

Comment: @Keltari sure, you can make a settings app that looks like the original, but can you also make it so that when you go to Settings and click system there, that your app is loaded instead? OP navigated to this page themselves.

Comment: well, all of it sounds like my screw up then. Which I can't really believe - but facts seem to be supporting that. Thanks everyone!